What type of critical point is at $(0,0)$ for $f(x,y)=0$?
Consider the function $f(x,y)=0$. If I were to conduct a partial second derivative test on $f$ at $(0,0)$, the result of the test is inconclusive. Can I ask what is the type of stationary point at $(0,0)$? Is it a maximum, minimum, saddle point, or neither?

It probably depends on the technicalities of your definitions, but the origin would be both a maximum and a minimum under mine:

Definitions:

$(x_0,y_0)$ is a (global) maximum of $g(x,y)$ if $g(x_0,y_0) \ge g(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ in $g$'s domain
$(x_0,y_0)$ is a (global) minimum of $g(x,y)$ if $g(x_0,y_0) \le g(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ in $g$'s domain


However, the definition I'm familiar for saddle point wouldn't work:

Definition: $(x_0,y_0)$ is a saddle point of $g$ if, in any open ball centered around $(x_0,y_0)$ (i.e. the points within some fixed distance of that point), there are points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ such that $f(x_1,y_1) < f(x_0,y_0) < f(x_2,y_2)$.

(Notice that this is why saddle points have their characteristic "shape" nearby, because the surface corresponding to the function $g$ will probably be increasing in one direction and decreasing in another.)
The strict inequality here prevents any point being a saddle point of the constant-zero function.

Agree with the point on the technicalities of the definition used. Maybe we see if there are further responses. That was what I was thinking about as well.

I just observed that if we changed the inequality signs of your definitions of global maximum and minimums from loose inequalities to strict inequalities, then the origin is neither max, min nor saddle.

It's hard to say that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point of the function $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y),$ where $g(t)=t^8\sin(t^{-1})$ for $t\neq 0$  and $g(0)=0. $ although the function satisfies your condition.
